# Changing Access Modifiers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been coding with C# and have run into some issues. I have been following [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0MR2bypYRE) and I have some errors. On line seven in Walking state code it says:

> Error CS0507 'WalkingState.ProcessMotion(Vector3)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 'BaseState.ProcessMotion(Vector3)'

What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Base state code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public abstract class BaseState : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected BaseMotor motor;

    #region baseState implementation
    public virtual void Construct()
    {
        motor = GetComponent<BaseMotor>();
    }
    public virtual void Destruct ()
    {
        Destroy(this);
    }
    public virtual void Transition ()
    {

    }
    #endregion

    public abstract Vector3 ProcessMotion(Vector3 input);
    public virtual Quaternion ProcessRotation(Vector3 input)
    {
        return transform.rotation;
    }
}
```

Walking state code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WalkingState : BaseState
{
    protected override Vector3 ProcessMotion(Vector3 input)
    {
        return input * motor.Speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot use protected when you're using a public from the base

Answer (score 9):

`ProcessMotion` is declared `public` in the base class. You need to also make it `public` in the derived class.

Instead of:

```
protected override Vector3 ProcessMotion(Vector3 input)
```

do:

```
public override Vector3 ProcessMotion(Vector3 input)
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is quite clear: the base class has the method marked as `public` but you're trying to change it into `protected` in the deriving class. This is not permitted, it must also be public in the deriving class.